# Pickadate not working

Tags: pickadate

I'm trying to use the [Pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/) plugin. I've got a very strange problem occurring. Sometimes the plugin decides to work and other times it doesn't.

I've added some console.log()'s to picker.js picker.date.js and picker.time.js and all are firing off as expected. Also if I check $.fn.pickadate to see if it exists it does. But then when I actually call $('.datepicker').pickadate() i'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).pickadate is not a function
```

If I refresh the page then the majority of times it all works as expected. But the odd occasion it doesn't.

Any suggestions on what this could be?

Comment: if you want something simpler and stable, this is worth looking: http://dbushell.github.io/Pikaday/ i'm using it on some backends works pretty well.

Comment: Hi @KatrinRaimond thanks for that. I was previously using Pikaday without an issue. But i'm needing some kind of time picking functionality which is why I opted for Pickadate.

Comment: i went the other way. was using pickadate, then switched to Pikaday for its simplicity.

Comment: I've just found [link](https://github.com/owenmead/Pikaday) which works perfectly it seems within a standalone HTML file. But when integrating into the likes of Shopify the same error occurs as with Pickadate. Whereby sometimes it will work and other times it won't. Very odd.

Comment: Load the jquery first, then your include your plugin, and put your plugins code in a `$( document ).ready(function() {});` block. see if it helps

Comment: Unfortunately i've tried that without success. As you will see in the attached image the three files are loading each time. If I look within the jQuery object I can see the pickadate and pickatime methods there. But then we get the damn issue again: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pickadate is not a function. [Image](http://postimg.org/image/orow1b37r/)

Answer (score 6):

Found your question and expanding on Sharky's comment, I went from:

```
   $('.datepicker').pickadate({
selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
selectYears: 3 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
  });
```

to:

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
       $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 3 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
  });
});
```

And it resolved my issue.

Edit: if it isn't clear from the code, this is an artifact of different js files loading at different speeds every time you load the page. The document.ready forces the picker initialization to wait until after all of the elements (including the picker library) are ready.